# Is there any way to hook-up all http requests from all browsers using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to have an app which would have access to all requests send from any browser at the current pc.

I don't want to have any kind of a proxy server,beacuse you have first adjust the browser settings.

Is this even possible using .NET ?

Comment: Hopefully this isn't for anything naughty, malware would love to do this

Comment: Nope I'd like to just blok some urls from my computer.. you now porn and stuff..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) has a .NET [API](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-api) that includes an event-based scripting system, allowing you to inspect all HTTP / HTTPS traffic from your machine. It's quite popular; there's even an [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiddler) tag for it. Technically, it *is* a proxy-based system; but because it reconfigures the default system-proxy on startup, traffic from browers with default proxy-settings enabled should be visible.

Comment: I didn't know that Fiddler has a .NET API!